# PHP exif loop over all meta data in a directory

Tags: php

I have the following code which reads all images on a directory. I want to get the comment meta data from all of the images and echo them, however, I am having a hard time getting the EXIF code to work. Can someone point out what I am doing wrong?

I get an 'Unable to open file in 'dir' on line 13 ( the line with EXIF )

```
        <?php

          $metalist = array();
          $img_folder = "./dir/";

          //use the directory class
          $imgs = dir($img_folder);

          // create an array of all files in directory that have the word 'pic' in them ( will be images )
          while ($file = $imgs->read()) {
            if (preg_match('/pic/', $file))
            {
              // create an array of the comment meta data
                $metalist[] = exif_read_data($file, 'COMMENT');
            }
          }
          closedir($imgs->handle);

          // echo each image's comment meta data
            foreach($metalist as $meta){
            echo $meta;
            }
          ?>
```

Thanks!

Comment: How do you know something's wrong? Incorrect output? No output?

Comment: I get an 'Unable to open file in 'dir' on line 13 ( the line with EXIF )

Comment: Can you copy/paste the *exact* error you're getting? I know it will help me as well as the rest of the community try and sort out what specifically your issue is.

Comment: Warning: exif_read_data() [function.exif-read-data]: Unable to open file in /dir/phptest.php on line 13   ( where phptest.php is my file that I am using to test )

Comment: You’ll have to prefix the file name with the path you specified in `$img_folder` …

Comment: Thanks @CBroe, since I am looping through a bunch of files, is there a way to do it dynamically?

Comment: Just concatenate `$img_folder` to `$file` …

Comment: Thanks its now working but it's just returning ArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArray